# navigationproblem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have problem .. i get debugerror i will used in json

```
Category *selectcategory = [[data categorys]objectAtindex:indexPath.row];
productlistviewcontroller *plviewcontroller = [[productlistviewcontroller alloc]initwithNibName:@"productlistviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
plviewcontroller.category = selectedcategory;
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:plviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

please check the my program. it doesnot goto nextviewcontroller.
console error is

> 2009-02-13 18:32:17.405
>   xxxxxxxx[1491:20b] * -[NsDecimalNumber
>   length]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xc3f10ff0 2009-02-13
>   18:32:17.406 xxxxxxxx[1491:20b]
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '** -[NsDecimalNumber length ]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xc3f10ff0' 2009-02-13 18:32:17.406
>   xxxxxxxx[1491:20b] Stack: (
>   2417225995, 2527100475, 2417255178,
>   2417248524, 2417248722, 22199, 9853,
>   816111650, 816149355, 2458333742,
>   2416728869, 2416729304, 827745792,
>   827745989, 816114848, 816160924, 9628,
>   9482 )

please send soluation...

Comment: Very unclear description. Please provide more details about your program, and use proper formatting (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: As you have pointed yourself you're getting errors while parsing json or while processing parsed data - so the code you've posted seems to be irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a lenght of an object that is `NSDecimalNumber`, but `NSDecimalNumber` doesn't have such a property. So the bug in your code is in one of the rows you call `something.length` or `[something length]`.

[NSDecimalNumber documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Problem is probably in productlistviewcontroller. Show us the code. Specially the place where you use "length".

Comment: get example in something.length;